# Git repository to Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gradle

I am developing a project in java, using eclipse, making backup by git (Bitbucket), and I decided to use build it using gradle.

Some of my source code can be used by other project, so I want to move them to other project and manage with another git repository. I want to add them as a dependency to the original project.  What should I have to write in `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) are the docs you need. Basically you need to create a standalone gradle project from the separate part. And then with the usage of `settings.gradle` create a multi project build. Maybe git modules will be also useful.